# Prestashop, There is 1 error You already have the maximum quantity available for this product

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Prestashop problems, I was adding products to my shop but when I go to my product page, I'm having this issue : ***There is 1 error
You already have the maximum quantity available for this product***.

[image: error]

Is there any possibilities to fix this issue please?

Comment: Did you solved this problem ?
Witch version of Prestashop are you using ?

Comment: Yes i have solved it, Thank you. I use 1.6.1.1 version

Comment: Could you please share the solution with us ?

Comment: You can answer your own question

Comment: What the hell, how is this a programming problem?

Comment: IMHO, this belongs on webapps.SE - there is no indice of this being a programming problem in neither question, answers or comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread is old, but I recently ran into the same error so this is my solution if anyone could find it useful:

If this happens with only a few combinations, it could be a problem related to custom database queries, ex.trying to change the main product of a specific combination with a custom script.

Please check these 2 tables: `ps_product_attribute` and `ps_product_attribute_shop`, and be sure that the field `product_id` in the row corresponding to the `product_attribute_id` throwing the error is the same.

If the 2 tables have 2 different values of `product_id` for the same `id_product_attribute`, Prestashop throws to the final user the error you specified

Keep in mind that there are other cases leading to the same error: to get the full list look at the `updateQty` method of the `html/classes/Cart.php` class, in the rows where it could return the `false` value (this is valid at least until Pretashop 1.4.6.x)

Answer (score 0):

You have the stock enable on your shop. So if the product have 1 quantity left, you can't add 2 quantity on your cart

Comment: Thank you for reply, greatly appreciated!! But the product in stock, i mean the quantity of product is 5, i dont know really. And i was just reading prestashop forums and some another forums, but i could not anything helpful yet. But is it fixable? if so, can you show me the way please step by step. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

It's can be related to your theme, for example wrong `id_product` passed into blockcart, do you have problem only with this product or with the others too?

Comment: Hi Krystian, Thank you for your answer. The product only with one product, Honestly, i have tried everything, almost no result at all. Regards, Dilshod